# Can I store a variable in an object?

Tags: vb.net, variables

Say I have a form application, and I draw a circle inside of it. Could I store a variable inside that circle object? Something like this?

```
Dim circle1.testVar As Integer = 1
```

Would that work, and is there a way to do this if it won't?

Comment: Only if the `Circle` class has a property `testVar`. And you would set it in this way: `circle1.testVar = 1`

Comment: I'm guessing I can only use in built properties- .left etc. here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot dynamically add properties to a `Control`.  you *can* use the existing `Tag` property of a control:

```
circle1.Tag = 1
```

Unfortunately `Tag` is of type `Object` so you're going to have to check for `Nothing` and/or cast the value when you retrieve it.

Comment: That's a shame, thanks for your answer :) Could the tag property be defined as an array and thus store several pieces of information?

Comment: You can store an array, but `Tag` is still defined as an `Object` so you'll still need to cast when _retrieving_ it.

Comment: Would that work through:

circle1.Tag = {"a","b"}
Console.WriteLine(circle1(0).ToString)

?

Comment: @niallmcfc You could assign it a Dictionary: `circle1.Tag = new Dictionary<string, int>()` for example to store multiple int values. To set a value: `((Dictionary<string, int>)circle1.Tag)["testVar"] = 1;`

Comment: that would be:`Console.WriteLine(circle1.Tag(0).ToString)`

Comment: Thanks for the help you two, I can get to work with that information :)